# Retrieving choice vlues from xsd

Tags: collections, xsd, jaxb

here is the part of xsd-scheme:

```
<xsd:complexType name="TGroups">
  <xsd:choice>
    <xsd:element name="GROUP1"/>
    <xsd:element name="GROUP2"/>
  </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Is there any way to get all TGroups values ("GROUP1", "GROUP2") from xsd as collection (Set, List, String[], ...) using JAXB or something else?

Thank you for reply.

Comment: The following shoul help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/04/xml-schema-to-java-xsd-choice.html